# Is this sentence, begining with “Je vous saurais gré”, correct?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

I am working on the following sentence :

> je vous saurais gré des instructions que vous voudriez **lui** donner à vos services habilités pour que ....

I think there is a problem in it. I propose the first alternative :

> je vous saurais gré des instructions que vous voudriez **les** donner à vos services habilités pour que ....

do I use **lui** ou **les** ?

Comment: using **les** doesn't make sense neither

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the *lui* or *les* pronoun and say :

> je vous saurais gré des instructions que vous voudriez donner à vos services habilités pour que ....

or, more idiomatic in French :

> je vous saurais gré de bien vouloir transmettre ces instructions à vos services compétents/habilités pour ...

because *"bien vouloir transmettre"* matches better the tone of *"je vous saurais"* expression.

Comment: correct, but suppose I want to stick to my sentence do I use **lui** ou **les** ?

Comment: @OSryx lui or les has not points there, you are already talking about "instructions" and you don't need a pronoun

Comment: ah I can remove LUI or LES without having problem ?

Comment: @OSryx: “Savoir gré de” must be followed by an action or an action-related substantive (something the person can agree with). What is relevant in this context is that the person agrees to the transmission of instructions, not to the instructions themselves). Your original formulation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I took the following clause as a whole : *"des instructions que vous voudriez donner"* so it looks correct to me. In my mind it was *je vous saurais gré* +  *des instructions que vous voudriez donner* = *je vous saurais gré* + *de la transmission de ces instructions*. Do you think the first formulation I gave is valid?